# Json object to Model MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

here is my Json Object

```
{
  "id":5,
  "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/5",
  "name":"Professional Experience II",
  "duration":"5.0",
  "description":"The course will talk in depth about every thing",
  "tutor": {
             "id":2,
             "email":"TA@mymail.com",
             "userName":"TA",
             "firstName":"T",
             "lastName":"A",
             "gender":0
           },
  "subject":
           {
             "id":2,
             "name":"Science"
           }
  }
```

and my model for is here

```
public class CourseModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Duration { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public TutorModel Tutor { get; set; }
        public SubjectModel Subject { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is how i am getting this object. I am able to get the jsonObject but not able to Deserialize it to its corresponding model

```
string url = "http://localhost:8001/api/courses/5";
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;        
  var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CourseModel>>(responseData);
  return View(data);
}
return View("Error:);
```

Error i am getting is

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Learning.Web.Models.CourseModel]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'id', line 1, position 6.

I am using WebApi and I am not sure what i am doing wrong here .. Any help will be appreciated

Updated:

Based on Shyju and Habib answer it does work if i deserialize it to a single instance but if i change the url to

```
string url = "http://localhost:8001/api/courses";
```

and deserialize it to List, i get same error, here is the json object

```
   {  
       "totalCount":32,
       "totalPages":4,
       "prevPageLink":"",
       "nextPageLink":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses?page=1&pageSize=10",
       "results":[  
          {  
             "id":1,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/1",
             "name":"History Teaching Methods 1",
             "duration":3.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: History Teaching Methods 1",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":1,
                "email":"h@outlook.com",
                "userName":"A,
                "firstName":"A",
                "lastName":"J",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":1,
                "name":"History"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":2,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/2",
             "name":"History Teaching Methods 2",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: History Teaching Methods 2",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":1,
                "email":"A.Jo@fg.com",
                "userName":"AJo",
                "firstName":"A",
                "lastName":"Jo",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":1,
                "name":"History"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":3,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/3",
             "name":"History Teaching Methods 3",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: History Teaching Methods 3",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":1,
                "email":"A@outlook.com",
                "userName":"A",
                "firstName":"A",
                "lastName":"J",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":1,
                "name":"History"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":4,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/4",
             "name":"Professional Experience 1 (Mathematics/Science)",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: Professional Experience 1 (Mathematics/Science)",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":2,
                "email":"T.A@mymail.com",
                "userName":"T",
                "firstName":"T",
                "lastName":"A",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":2,
                "name":"Science"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":5,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/5",
             "name":"Professional Experience 2 (Mathematics/Science)",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: Professional Experience 2 (Mathematics/Science)",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":2,
                "email":"TA@mymail.com",
                "userName":"T",
                "firstName":"T",
                "lastName":"A",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":2,
                "name":"Science"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":6,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/6",
             "name":"Professional Experience 3 (Mathematics/Science)",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: Professional Experience 3 (Mathematics/Science)",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":2,
                "email":"TA@mymail.com",
                "userName":"T",
                "firstName":"T",
                "lastName":"A",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":2,
                "name":"Science"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":7,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/7",
             "name":"Geography Teaching Methods 1",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: Geography Teaching Methods 1",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":3,
                "email":"TW@mymail.com",
                "userName":"Ti",
                "firstName":"T",
                "lastName":"W",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":3,
                "name":"Geography"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":8,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/8",
             "name":"Geography Teaching Methods 2",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: Geography Teaching Methods 2",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":3,
                "email":"p@mymail.com",
                "userName":"f",
                "firstName":"f",
                "lastName":"f",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":3,
                "name":"Geography"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":9,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/9",
             "name":"Geography Teaching Methods 3",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: Geography Teaching Methods 3",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":3,
                "email":"s.s@mymail.com",
                "userName":"s",
                "firstName":"s",
                "lastName":"s",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":3,
                "name":"Geography"
             }
          },
          {  
             "id":10,
             "url":"http://localhost:8001/api/courses/10",
             "name":"English Education 1",
             "duration":5.0,
             "description":"The course will talk in depth about: English Education 1",
             "tutor":{  
                "id":4,
                "email":"g.g@outlook.com",
                "userName":"g",
                "firstName":"g",
                "lastName":"g",
                "gender":0
             },
             "subject":{  
                "id":4,
                "name":"English"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON represent a single instance of `CourseModel`. You should be deserializing that to a single instance of `CourseModel`, not a List of those.

This should work.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CourseModel>(responseData);
```

Comment: It does work for single instance .. but if i change the url to                    string url = "http://localhost:8001/api/courses"; and deserialize it to List i get same error .. any idea?

Comment: because your json data is for a single instance, not an array of them.

Comment: if i dont use parameter i.e. 5 i get different Json object, do i need to display the other Json object also?

Comment: So you need to conditionally deserialize to a single instance or a list based  on whether you are passing an Id (Ex: 5) in your REST API call.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier .. i updated the question

Comment: Are you having the same action method which shows a list of item and a single item ? Where are you getting the value `5` from ? What is your razor view strongly typed to ?

Comment: No, i have different action methods for all courses and individual course.  I had this @model IEnumerable<Learning.Web.Models.CourseModel> in view but couldn't work it out. I have to display all courses first and then when user click on a course i will grab that id .. that's what my thinking was so far

Comment: So for the action method for list of courses, you need to serialize to `List<CourseModel>` and return the data to a view which is strongly typed to a `List<CourseModel>` . For showing a single course, You should deserialize to `CourseModel` and return that data to a view which is storngly typed to a single instance(Ex : `@model CourseModel`)

Comment: so i need two different views?

Comment: You said you have 2 action methods (So you should have 2 views by default), But you can use a single view if you want ( you have to use `return View("YourSingleViewName")`. But you need to convert your data from both the action methods to same type which this view is stongly typed to. I suggest you read the basics of asp.net mvc before writing any more code further.

Comment: yeah i agree with your last statement .. probably i need to 're-visit' mvc concepts ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have setup your `Tutor` and `Subject` class properly the **error is because you are trying to deserialize a single object to a `List<T>`**

DO:

```
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CourseModel>(responseData);
```

Also to create related model, you can paste your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ and get the generated models, the would look like:

```
public class Tutor
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public int gender { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class CourseModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Tutor tutor { get; set; }
    public Subject subject { get; set; }
}
```